# xDebug : Output traces in php script?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have tried to use xDebug on my local Ubuntu environment to speed up development and it's a great asset.

However, I would like to see the output of the Trace function directly in the browser, at the end of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xdebug_start_trace / xdebug_stop_trace functions only write to a file. These are what you are talking about right? But you could then read that file at the very end of your script so it would display.

```
xdebug_start_trace('/path/to/log');
blah blah
xdebug_stop_trace();
readfile('/path/to/log');
```

If you need to step through your code regularly though, I would suggest using an external program (http://xdebug.org/docs/remote). Using one of those with xdebug will let you step through your code, set breakpoints, etc...